# How to update swift 2.3 project to latest swift 4

Tags: ios, cocoapods, swift4, swift2

I am having too many cocoapods installed. It shows too many compile time errors. How to solve this? 
I am new to swift so looking for help. 
Thanks

Comment: For your code update, use XCode 9 to update more easily from 2.3 to 3, and upgrade XCode to 10 and use it to go from 3 to 4. For pods, updates each one of them by reading their documentation to the target Swift Version by specifying the version of it. Check before hand that they are all convertible to Swift 4. Be careful, there may be more changes that only Swift (renaming, etc.)

Comment: @Larme, you have the wrong versions - Xcode 8 will do an upgrade to Swift 3 and Xcode 9 does the upgrade to Swift 4.

Comment: Glad to be of help. I was composing an answer when @paresh posted one and thought I had misread what you were trying to do. You *do* have one other alternative - open your project in Xcode 9, blow past the popup stating Swift 2.3 isn't compatible, set the project language to Swift 4 and *manually correct all the errors. I've done this a few times and while tedious, it works.

Answer (score 0):

- Choose auto upgrade after opening the project in Xcode 9.
- In Podfile refer to the framework built in swift 4. Add below script in your Podfile and do a pod install, which will set the swift version of all pod targets to 4.

  post_install do |installer|

  ```
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4'
      end
  end
  ```

  end

Hope this helps in proceeding in upgrading the application to swift4

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am having deprecated pods which are not updated for swift 4. So how to fix this?

Comment: are those pods are closed or accessible?? means the code inside the framework are accessible by you? if yes, then manually upgrade those code also

Comment: I have worked with pod install your way but it shows more errors, I have checked with deprecated pods causing errors. Is there any other way I can fix with deprecated pods?